# Imagens aparece no localhost, mas não so servidor online

Tags: html

Pessoal estou com o site no localhost rodando certinho, mas quando eu upo ele pro server online algumas imagens não aparecem, eu ja upei as imagens, ja apaguei todo o site e coloquei de novo, é exatamente o mesmo código, mas no local funciona e no server online não. Alguem que souber o que está acontecendo e puder ajudar ficaria grato, estou há horas tentando resolver o problema sem sucesso

pastas="public_html\img\paginas\renatostudio\
dentro de \renatostudio\ ,as pastas são:
aniversário
casamento\
ensaio\
smash\

agora o código:

```
                         <div class="iso-box aniversario col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <a href="img/paginas/renatostudio/aniversario/5.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio-gallery"><img src="img/paginas/renatostudio/aniversario/5.jpg" alt="portfolio img"></a>
                         </div>

                         <div class="iso-box html casamento col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <a href="img/paginas/renatostudio/casamento/.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio-gallery"><img src="img/paginas/renatostudio/casamento/1.jpg" alt="portfolio img"></a>
                         </div>

                         <div class="iso-box aniversario col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <a href="img/paginas/renatostudio/aniversario/4.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio-gallery"><img src="img/paginas/renatostudio/aniversario/4.jpg" alt="portfolio img"></a>
                         </div>

                         <div class="iso-box ensaio col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <a href="img/paginas/renatostudio/ensaio/4.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio-gallery"><img src="img/paginas/renatostudio/ensaio/4.jpg" alt="portfolio img"></a>
                         </div>

                          <div class="iso-box casamento col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <a href="img/paginas/renatostudio/casamento/3.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio-gallery"><img src="img/paginas/renatostudio/casamento/3.jpg" alt="portfolio img"></a>
                         </div>

                          <div class="iso-box smash col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <a href="img/paginas/renatostudio/smash/2.jpg.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio-gallery"><img src="img/paginas/renatostudio/smash/2.jpg" alt="portfolio img"></a>
                         </div>

                          <div class="iso-box smash col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <a href="img/paginas/renatostudio/smash/11.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio-gallery"><img src="img/paginas/renatostudio/smash/11.jpg" alt="portfolio img"></a>
                         </div>


                         <div class="iso-box ensaio col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <a href="img/paginas/renatostudio/ensaio/5.jpg.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio-gallery"><img src="img/paginas/renatostudio/ensaio/5.jpg" alt="portfolio img"></a>
                         </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você precisa ser mais específico em sua pergunta! Se usou o path relativo para suas urls de imagens pode ocasionar problemas utilize o google chrome developper para depurar o erro.

Comment: Poste o código das imagens, a sua estrutura de pastas local e o programa que está usando pra rodar o localhost.

Comment: tem no git? posso dar uma olhada no código?

Comment: Poste também os erros que aparecem no console do chrome...

Comment: n tenho no git mas a pagina a a qual me refiro vc pode ver online: http://oatalho.com.br/renatostudio

Comment: Boa tarde.
Se você reparar no código tem exemplos como : "/2.jpg.jpg" ou "/.jpg" e não está encontrando as imagens na pasta. Fora isso, na hora de publicar suas imagens, elas foram adicionadas no projeto também ou no servidor?

Comment: Confira se as imagens e a mesma estrutura de pastas está publicada no servidor.

Comment: Tente colocar um "./" antes de dos img

Comment: duas com jpg.jpg e as demais o caminho deve estar errado mesmo

Comment: 1-as imagens com jpg.jpg pertencem ao link que o js abre quando se clica na imagem, e não na imagem que aparece. Obrigado aos que notaram, eu consertei mas isso não resolveu o problema ainda
2-./ não funcionou :(
3-as estruturas de pastas estão corretas, porque eu já apaguei todo o conteudo do servidor e passe exatamente o mesmo projeto, e o local funciona e o online não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o erro não era no código, mas nas imagens! Eu não sei pq, mas dps que passei as imagens no tiny.jpg elas pararam de aparecer no server online, mas dps que que eu abri no photoshop e salvei novamente (não fiz nenhuma alteração) elas passaram a aparecer. Se alguem souber explicar eu adoraria :)

Answer (score 0):

Se seu `index.html` estiver na pasta `public_html`, basta colocar um `./` atrás de `img` em cada atributo `href` de suas imagens.

Comment: n deu certo... aparentemente o erro é com as fotos. Não sei pq, mas eu recoloquei algumas sem ter passado pelo tiny.jpg e das 12 imagens, 6 apareceram. Só não sei pq diabos isso acontece : /